# Infinite Loop and System.exit(0) in java

Tags: java, loops

I was wondering if it was bad coding practice and/or some consequences if I make an infinite loop(i am checking if a program has started) and when a condition Im checking becomes true, I use system.exit.

Comment: Where you use infinite loop? For what purpose you use that? Give the specific piece of code.

Comment: Doesn't sound good. Any code examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be better off using the java.util.Timer and java.util.TimerTask classes, and recursively relaunching the timer as it expires. As the above post says there is nothing inherently wrong with using System.exit.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Timer timer = new Timer(); //create a new timer
    timer.schedule(new TaskLoop(), 1000); //schedule the task for 1000ms (1 sec)
}
class TaskLoop extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("here"); //timer's up, do whatever you need to do
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TaskLoop(), 1000); //start another timer.
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the timer. Its definitely better than an infinite loop.

Answer (score 9):

An active wait loop is usually a terrible idea. It makes the entire machine slower (including start-up of the other program). Find a way to just listen for a program start event. Without any details of your code, I can't provide any more specific suggestions.

There's nothing inherently wrong with calling `System.exit(0)`; it all depends on what kind of program it is. (E.g., a Swing application should just set `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` or `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` for the application's JFrame and then close the frame.)

Comment: Don't worry, I put a 100 millisecond sleep on the thread so as not to kill the cpu. I would love to listen to a program start event. Can you share a link or sample code of a start event listener?

Comment: @UniversalCreator1 - It kind of depends on whether you can get the other program to cooperate. If you are also writing the other program there are various techniques for it to signal to the monitor program that it has started.

Comment: I cannot control the external program, that would of made it way to easy! I thought when you said a program start event, windows would notify java there is a program launched which in turn would fire an internal event. Anyway, the answer Jack Straw gave works perfectly and doesn't require an infinite loop.